# Is it possible to inject a specific configuration class bound as a suboption and not to IConfiguration<MyType>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a class that I want injected into some controllers. It has a few dependencies that I want to be automatically injected. Specifically this class requires a configuration object be passed in.

So my *appsettings.json* file looks something like this:

```
{
    "MyType": {
        "Option1": "value"
    }
}
```

And I have a class that mirrors this, ex.

```
public class MyTypeConfig
{
    public string Option1 { get; set; }
}
```

I have registered this in my startup class.

```
services.Configure<MyTypeConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("MyType"));
```

However, I want to receive a "naked" version of `MyTypeConfig` in the class being instantiated, NOT `IConfigureOptions<MyTypeConfig>` which is what the DI system seems to want to inject.

The constructor for the class being injected looks liked this (which works):

```
public MySampleClass(IHttpClientFactory httpClient, IConfigureOptions<MyTypeConfig> configuration, ILogger<MySampleClass> logger)
```

However, this is really want I want:

```
public MySampleClass(IHttpClientFactory httpClient, MyTypeConfig configuration, ILogger<MySampleClass> logger)
```

I've looked through the topic on the Microsoft site, here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2

But I'm not really finding an answer.

How can I just inject the MyTypeConfig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the class from configuration during startup and register it with the service collection.

```
MyTypeConfig config = Configuration.GetSection("MyType").Get<MyTypeConfig>();
services.AddSingleton<MyTypeConfig>(config);
```

Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core : Bind to an object graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#bind-to-an-object-graph)

Comment: Thanks. Here's what I was doing, but yours is a bit closer to what I wanted (I actually was assuming this was supported somehow via the config classes more directly).

            services.AddTransient<MyTypeConfig>((p) =>
            {
                var config = Configuration.Get<MyTypeConfig>();
                return config;
            });

Answer (score 0):

In 2022, imho, there is a better way to do that
[image: in 2022, there's a better way]

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The OP wants to inject `MyTypeConfig` not `IOptions<MyTypeConfig>`.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman You are right. However, I personally like this alternative. This way you can exactly know that the objects with any name are from your configuration.